# Module function not returning an answer

Tags: c, function, pointers, crash

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
func (int x, int apple);
int main()

{int x,apple;

 scanf("%d",x);
 func (x,apple);

 if (apple==0)
    printf("Yes");
    else if (apple==1)
        printf("no!");
}

func (int x,int apple )

{

 if ((x%7)==0||(x%11)==0||(x%13)==0)
    apple=0;
 else
    apple=1;

}
```

The idea of the whole thing is that the function tests whether the entered value x is a multiple of 7,11 or 13, and gives a result.

The function works just fine (In terms of that the compiler doesn't detect an error and launches just fine) but s what I get on my compiler's window (After I enter any value) is that the process returned 1 and nothing else. And prior to that, it gives me a windows error and that the project I am working on crashed.

I am pretty much forced to use pointers, so what am I doing wrong?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't see any pointers here, except the one you neglected to give `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a mismatch between the format specifier `"%d"` and the argument type being provided to `scanf()`, an `int` is specified when it must be an `int*`: this is undefined behaviour. Pass the *address* of `x` to [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and ensure `x` is assigned a value by checking return value of `scanf()` which returns the number of successful assignments:

  ```
  if (scanf("%d",&x) == 1)
  {
  }
  ```
- State return type of `void` for `func()`.
- Pass the *address* of `apple` to `func()` (and change argument to `int* apple`) so any change made to `apple` within `func()` is visible to the caller:

  ```
  void func (int x, int* apple)
  {
      /* Dereference 'apple' for assignment. */
      *apple = 0;
  }
  ```